# I am getting unbound local error while pickle loading a file

Tags: python, function, oop, pickle, file-handling

I am. Pickle loading two files one by one and I am getting an unbound local error while closing them.
I used exception handling while opening the file and in the except block it shows unbound local error while closing the files.
 though i used filenotfound In the exception block as it is a necessary exception to handle.no indentation errors are there i just am not able to handle the error stating.

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\t.py", line 648, in dispdeisel
    fdl=open("D:/Python/deisel/"+str(z1)+".txt","rb+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:/Python/deisel/Wed Apr 29 2020.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\t.py", line 820, in <module>
    b.dispdeisel()
  File "d:\Python\t.py", line 664, in dispdeisel
    fdl.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fdl' referenced before assignment"
```

```
k1=[]

        try:
            tdc=open("D:/Python/deisel/collection.txt","rb+")
            fdl=open("D:/Python/deisel/"+str(z1)+".txt","rb+")
            while True:
                self.f1=pickle.load(tdc)
                self.fd=pickle.load(fdl)
                k1.append(self.f1)
                kd.append(self.fd)
        except EOFError and FileNotFoundError:
            qa=0
            for i in kd:
                if "L"in i:
                    qa1=i[:-1]
                    qa=qa+int(qa)
                else:
                    qa=qa+int(i[0])
            print (" Total Collection for Deisel on date ",z1,"is",qa)
            tdc.close()
            fdl.close()
```

Comment: You should share your code, or similar code that causes the same issue and you should provide the actual error message instead of just the name - however, an unbound local error is normally the result of referencing a global variable inside a function without declaring it as a global. If that makes no sense, provide some code and someone can adjust your code to show what needs to be different.

Comment: sir please look to the above mentioned code which i have added to my question.is the error popping due to use of exception handles or is it something else?plz guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, when this line is reached (and causes an error):

```
tdc=open("D:/Python/deisel/collection.txt","rb+")
```

.. then the next line will never be executed and `fdl` won't have a value.

After the error, execution continues after `except EOFError and FileNotFoundError:` and this line is reached:

```
fdl.close()
```

Since `fdl` was never defined (as that line was skipped), it has no value and that's the cause of your error.

One way of fixing it would be to deal with the exceptions more cleanly:

```
class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self, z1):
        # initialisation
        qa = 0
        kd = []
        k1 = []
        try:
            tdc = open("D:/Python/deisel/collection.txt","rb+")
            try:
                fdl = open("D:/Python/deisel/"+str(z1)+".txt","rb+")
                try:
                    try:
                        while True:
                            self.f1 = pickle.load(tdc)
                            self.fd = pickle.load(fdl)
                            k1.append(self.f1)
                            kd.append(self.fd)
                    except EOFError:
                        pass  # no message needed, but not the nicest way to use the exception
                    for i in kd:
                        if "L" in i:
                            # this bit makes no sense to me, but it's not relevant
                            qa1 = i[:-1]
                            qa = qa + int(qa)
                        else:
                            qa = qa + int(i[0])
                    print(" Total Collection for Deisel on date ", z1, "is", qa)
                finally:
                    tdc.close()
                    fdl.close()
            except FileNotFoundError:
                tdc.close()  # this is open, closing it
                pass  # some error message perhaps?
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass  # some error message perhaps?
```

This is better, but not very Pythonic and only illustrates how you could solve your problem - it's not at all how I recommend you write this.

Closer to what you probably need:

```
import pickle


class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self, z1):
        # initialisation
        qa = 0
        kd = []
        k1 = []
        try:
            with open("D:/Python/deisel/collection.txt","rb+") as tdc:
            try:
                with open("D:/Python/deisel/"+str(z1)+".txt","rb+") as fdl:
                    try:
                        while True:
                            self.f1 = pickle.load(tdc)
                            self.fd = pickle.load(fdl)
                            k1.append(self.f1)
                            kd.append(self.fd)
                    except EOFError:
                        pass  # no message needed, but not the nicest way to use the exception
                    for i in kd:
                        if "L" in i:
                            # this bit makes no sense to me, but it's not relevant
                            qa1 = i[:-1]
                            qa = qa + int(qa)
                        else:
                            qa = qa + int(i[0])
                    print(" Total Collection for Deisel on date ", z1, "is", qa)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass  # some error message perhaps?
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass  # some error message perhaps?
```

`with` does exactly what you're trying to do and cleans up the file handle, guaranteed.

And this still has the issue of getting multiple pickles from files, with no guarantee the number of pickles will be the same for both - if you write these pickles yourself, why not pickle a list of objects and avoid that mess?

In general, don't use exceptions if you expect them to occur, instead code directly what you expect - it's easier to read and maintain and it generally performs better:

```
import pickle
from pathlib import Path


class SomeClass:
    def some_method(self, z1):
        # initialisation
        qa = 0
        kd = []
        k1 = []
        fn1 = "D:/Python/deisel/collection.txt"
        fn2 = "D:/Python/deisel/"+str(z1)+".txt"

        if not Path(fn1).is_file() or not Path(fn2).is_file():
            return  # some error message perhaps?

        with open(fn1, "rb+") as tdc:
            with open(fn2, "rb+") as fdl:
                try:
                    while True:
                        # not using self.f1 and .fd, since it seems they are just local
                        # also: why are you loading k1 anyway, you're not using it?
                        k1.append(pickle.load(tdc))
                        kd.append(pickle.load(fdl))
                except EOFError:
                    pass  # no message needed, but not the nicest way to use the exception
                for i in kd:
                    if "L" in i:
                        qa1 = i[:-1]
                        qa = qa + int(qa)
                    else:
                        qa = qa + int(i[0])
                print(" Total Collection for Deisel on date ", z1, "is", qa)
```

I don't know about the rest of your code, but you could probably get rid of the EOF exception as well, if you pickle in a predictable way and it seems the load of `f1` into `k1` only serves the purpose of being a possible limit to how many elements are loaded from `kd`, which is wasteful.

Note how, with every example, the code gets more readable and shorter. Shorter by itself is not a good thing, but if your code becomes more easy to read and understand, performs better and is shorter on top, you know you're on the right track.

Comment: Thanku so. Much sir.i have implemented all of your modifications in the code. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help - if you think the answer answers your question, please click the check mark so that the question appears answered and others can find it as well